# Using DisplayNameFor and DisplayFor whilst looping list within model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have created a ViewModel which I am using as the model for my view. Within the view model it contains the following definition:

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel> ItemOptions { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see it contains a List<> named ItemOptions. My view model is tied to ItemDetailViewModel. Within the view I loop through each element in the list and output them:

```
@model app1.Models.ViewModels.ItemDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Item " + @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemId);
}

//...
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (app1.Models.ViewModels.ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel ItemOption in Model.ItemOptions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@ItemOption.Active</td>
            <td>@ItemOption.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
//...
```

What I want to be able to do is instead of hard coding the name and values, I want to be able to user the helpers I use else where within the page, such as:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCode)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemCode)
```

I've tried the following

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemOptions.ItemCode)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemOptions.ItemCode)
```

But this gives the following error:

> Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.List<[].Models.ViewModels.ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ItemCode' and no extension method
>   'ItemCode' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<[].Models.ViewModels.ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   ....\Views\Item\Details.cshtml  87  81  []

I've also tried doing it off the ItemOption object which I loop on but get similar issues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Going from the `ItemOption` should work fine: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => ItemOption.ItemCode)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => ItemOption.ItemCode)`

Comment: Ah yes, the DisplayFor works fine within the loop. How would I reference the headers though as this is outside the loop so I don't have ItemOption set.

Comment: You can use Partial View Templates. See this for some details on how to go about doing that.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2326405/1181408

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ItemOptions` is a `List<>`, so by itself it doesn't have a definition for `ItemCode`.  Any element in that list, however, does.  Something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemOptions.First().ItemCode)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemOptions.First().ItemCode)
```

At first it might look like this would potentially throw an error if the list has no elements, but it's a quirk of the view engine that it doesn't actually *call* `.First()` on the list, it just uses the reference to determine the type from which it gleans information.  The type returned by `First()` is `ItemDetailItemOptionViewModel` in this case, so it then gets the meta-data it needs from that type.